# EF Core owned property state propagation to parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**What I have:**

```
// Parent entity
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

// Owned Type
public class Address {
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

...

// Configuration
public class PersonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(person => person.Address);
    }
}

...

// On Address (owned property) modified:
bool personModified = _dbContext.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<Person>()
    .Any(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified);

Console.WriteLine(personModified);  // -> false
```

**What I want:** to be able to detect State changes on parent entity (`Person`) level when owned property (`Address`) become `Modified` (`personModified == true`). In other words, I want to propagate owned property state to parent entity level. Is this even possible?

Btw. I'm using EF Core v2.1.1.

Comment: It's not directly supported, but you can use some heck for this. so When you are modifying owned property then you update any column value with the same value in the parent class.

Comment: @vivek-nuna Thank you for reply. That would be much easier fix then the one we currently have (detecting owned property changes on parent entity level through reflection). But it is not always applicable and it is easy to forget to "touch" parent entity property.

Comment: You can open a bug here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following custom extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsModified(this EntityEntry entry) =>
        entry.State == EntityState.Modified ||
        entry.References.Any(r => r.TargetEntry != null && r.TargetEntry.Metadata.IsOwned() && IsModified(r.TargetEntry));
}
```

In other words, additionally to checking the direct entity entry state we check recursively the entry states for each owned entities.

Applying it to your sample:

```
// On Address (owned property) modified:
bool personModified = _dbContext.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<Person>()
    .Any(x => x.IsModified());

Console.WriteLine(personModified);  // -> true
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm accepting the answer, it is much better solution the the one we used. Small edit: `r.TargetEntry != null` condition is missing, because I get null reference exception.

Comment: This does not seem to work (anymore) the `References` collection of my entity has no entries (even though it has modified Owned children). Any suggestions? In my case I'm using OwnsMany() though.

Comment: @Robba `References` returns only *reference* navigation properties, while `OwnsMany` are *collections`. So this never worked for such (can't recall if they were available at that time). They are available through `Collections`, but I don't know how collection is supposed to be detected as modified.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev I saw the Collections property using the debugging tools, but I seem to recall that the entries in there are the actual entities and not the EntitySate objects. Nevertheless I'll have another look at that, thanks.

Comment: I am getting NullReferenceException somewhere deep in EF when I am using this solution. (technically something goes wrong when I access entry.References in concurrent way) Not everytime, non deterministic. I suppouse this is side effect of concurrency. Generally, I strongly DO NOT recommend this code :(

edit: This code is ok, but of course EF sucks :(

Comment: Update: I can confirm now that running above `IsModified` extension in parallel is not possible. EF Core is not thread safe here. In one thread is ok.

Comment: @PiotrKwiatek They are not thread safe anywhere. It is documented - don't share `DbContext` instance between multiple threads. If you do so, it is on your own risk - somewhere/sometimes it might work, somewhere/sometimes it might not. That's the definition of "not supported" - the behavior is undefined. So no need to confirm the obvious :)

Comment: I am not sharing `DbContext`, but just running in parallel `IsModified` extensions. Anyway using `EntityEntry entry` in Parallel might be the same what You are talking about so... Ok. Thanks.

Comment: @PiotrKwiatek calling DbContext methods (extension or not)  "in parallel" is the same as sharing it between multiple threads. By `DbContext` they mean everything associated with it. `EntityEntry` is part of the change tracker which is part of the db context.